# Is there a way to store a large number precisely in R?

Tags: r, biginteger

Is there a way to store a large number precicely in R?

**double** is stored as a binary fraction and its precision varies with the value, and **integer** has limited range of 4 bytes.

What if I wanted to store a very large number precisely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `bigz` class from the `gmp`package:

```
> library("gmp")
> 2^10000
[1] Inf
> 2^(as.bigz(10000))
[1] "199506.... and a LOT of more numbers!
```

It basically stores the number as a string and so avoiding the integer/double limits.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by *large number*:

- If you want numbers above the top end of double precision arithmetic, there is the **[Brobdingnag](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html)** package
- If you want more precision there are the **[gmp](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html)** and related **[Rmpfr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html)** packages.